# Lightning:inputField not allowing decimal numbers to be inserted

Tags: lightning, lightning-inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

I am using  `<lightning:recordEditForm>` and  `<lightning:inputField fieldName="customField"/>` to create a form. My custom field is Number field with setup number(16,2) - length 16, decimal places 2.

When i try to insert decimal number to my form, i get the error message:

[image]

Anybody faced the problem?

Thanks in andvance.

Comment: What locale is related to your current user?

Comment: What you mean by locale? I am testing this as system administrator. Also if i create a same field on lets say Account object, which has standard form for creating a record, then the decimal number works. Problem is, that on my custom object, i am using lightning component to override my record createion form. And  i use lightning:inputField to display all fields i want. Everything work fine - date, test, lookup etc. But number fields are not in right configuration ( not allowing decimals ).

Comment: One more thing- it displays error and rounds number to full integer, e.g if i write 15.59 its shows 16 when not onfocus, But allows to save record and on detail page the number is decimal.

Comment: could you try with a comma instead of a period?

Answer (score 7):

The issue seems in the way *lightning:inputField* has been implemented. Here are some interesting findings around *lightning:inputField* implementation.

And I posted an **[idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E99QQAS)** based on this issue on the idea forum for this.

---

Once rendered, *lightning:inputField* with underlying field as Decimal is rendered as HTML `<input type="number" ../>`. This HTML tag has a **[step](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp)** attribute which determines the decimal increment value for the input being entered in the field. If you observe the *step* value for a rendered inputField component on Chrome console, it shows as `step="1"` with all other details.

Interestingly, there's no **step** attribute available for *lightning:inputField*, thus you really cannot control this value and its up to the framework to define that, which looks like it's only defaulted as 1 in this case.

```
My code as on component:
<lightning:inputField aura:id="customField" fieldName="jdforce__My_Decimal_Field__c"  />

As rendered:  
<input type="number" id="input-1" step="1" name="jdforce__My_Decimal_Field__c" class="slds-input" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1;">
```

And if you edit the generated HTML to change the step value in there, you will see that you don't get the error.

---

Now, if you use `lightning:input` which is derived from HTML `input` tag, you have an option of setting the **[step](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm)** value for this component. So if I have something as below in my component, I can control what are the allowable values.

```
My code as on component:
<lightning:input type="number" name="decimal" label="Enter a decimal value" step="0.01"/>

As rendered:
<input type="number" id="6:0" step="0.01" name="decimal" class="slds-input" style="position:absolute;" data-aura-rendered-by="15:0" >
```

Now in this scenario, if I attempt to say enter a value of *15.591*, I get the same error (*Your entry isn't a valid increment*) because my step is defined to allow only two decimal places in this case.

---

Your Option:

To mitigate this scenario, you may just like to utilize *lightning:input* for decimal fields only in conjunction with *lightning:inputField* for other fields and during the component initialization, fetch the value from underlying record for all decimal fields and set the values in there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I inspected the dev console too and noticed that the step is 1 and `lightning:inputField`is not offering us any flexibility on that. Currently i am trying to use `lighning:input` and add new field to the `recordEditForm` component with value from `lighning:input` field before i submit the form. Not sure if i can add fields to `recordEditForm` in  `onsubmit()` function. Anyways thanks again for helping :)

Comment: Lightning:input is beta so keep your client team informed of that. In summer 2018 lightning input has had lot of issues

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below:

<lightning:input type="number" name="decimal" label="Enter a decimal value" **step="any"**/>

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! The only difference I see between your answer and the other answer is that you changed the `step` value to be `"any"` rather than `"0.01"`. But the OP stated that the field has 2 decimal places. Won't `"any"` allow for more than two decimal places to be entered?

Comment: Thank you. My understanding was different I was thinking solution to remove this error for all the decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<lightning:input type="number" name="ItemPrice"
    label="Price" value="12345" step=".01" formatter="currency"/>
```

for more information refer Number Validation in below url
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation